# cokriging and generalised linear spatial models

Tags: spatial, geostatistics

The answer to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30643/confusion-regarding-kriging) gave me an interesting idea. The part that interested me was a brief description of kriging concluded by

> The way, kriging as usually practiced is not quite the same as
>   least squares estimation, because Σ is estimated in a preliminary
>   procedure (known as "variography") using the same data. That is
>   contrary to the assumptions of this derivation, which assumed Σ was
>   known (and a fortiori independent of the data). Thus, at the very
>   outset, kriging has some conceptual and statistical flaws built into
>   it. Thoughtful practitioners have always been aware of this and found
>   various creative ways to (try to) justify the inconsistencies. (Having
>   lots of data can really help.) [Procedures now exist](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geoRglm/index.html) for simultaneously
>   estimating Σ and predicting a collection of values at unknown
>   locations. They require slightly stronger assumptions (multivariate
>   normality) in order to accomplish this feat.

The question I had from this was is there a similar method for cokriging like how generalized spatial models are an improvement upon kriging? Basically a technique that doesn't assume anything on Sigma or mu and uses the secondary variate.